# How to check if a user is connected to a voice channel in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I want to check if a user is connected to a voice channel because I want create a command that kicks a user from a voice channel. Therefore I check with

```
const user: any = interaction.options.getUser('user');
const member = interaction.guild?.members.cache.get(user.id);

if (member?.voice.channel) {
   // Kick member
} else {
  // Not connected
}
```

if the user is connected to a channel. Which works fine for the first time after the Bot starts. But after the member was kicked for the first time the bot always tries to kick the member from the voice channel even when the member is not connected to a voice channel. How can I check if the member is connected to a voice channel even after the member got kicked for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the ? on those statements, as I don’t use typescript but if you do, then add them where needed. But the below code will work for you.

```js
const member2kick = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.options.getUser('user');
// check if the member.voice.channelId contains a channel ID
    if (member2kick.voice.channelId) {
        member2kick.voice.disconnect()
        return interaction.reply({
            content: `${member2kick} kicked from <#${member2kick.voice.channelId}>.`,
            ephemeral: true
        })
    } else {
        return interaction.reply({
            content: `${member2kick} is not in a voice channel at this moment, cant kick them.`,
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
```